# Error when using read.table

Tags: r

I need help to put a `.txt` file into R. I'm trying to input a text document into R for a stats class but it isn't working.

I put it in `read.table("TransaniaIncomes.txt", header=TRUE)` but the following message keeps coming up:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition:
>   Warning message: In file(file, "rt") : cannot open file
>   'TransaniaIncomes.txt': No such file or directory

I don't really know what to do. The file extends for several thousand characters like this in 5 straight columns:

```
3.755556 13.51542 14.4545 19.93651 21.62806
57.48426 7.282404 38.48386 10.22754 9.9399
21.38976 6.675126 32.14614 53.96588 12.37087
30.35346 10.20072 2.650464 26.84042 14.13381
```

Comment: You need to tell R where to find the file. You can either specify the full filepath (e.g., `read.table("C:/user/path/to/Transanialcomes.txt")`) or you can set the working directory to the containing folder with `setwd()` or by navigating to it in RStudio's File tab and clicking `More` > `Set as working directory`.

Answer (score 2):

**I.** `getwd()`

Make sure your `.txt` file is in the current working directory of RStudio. To check current working directory of RStudio, type in console: `getwd()` and see if your file exists in that path.

**II.** `setwd()`

If your file exists in some other path, you can set that path in RStudio using `setwd()`and then run the `read.table()` command. Example:

```
    setwd("C:/My/Path/To/TextFile")  # The .txt file would be in TextFile folder
    read.table("TransaniaIncomes.txt", header=TRUE)
```

**III.** `file.choose()`

To avoid path setting and you know where your file is stored, you can use `file.choose()` function inside `read.table()` which will open up a interactive dialog box to go and select your `.txt` file from PC, wherever it is.

```
     read.table(file.choose(), sep="\t", header=TRUE)  # Choose "TransaniaIncomes.txt"
```

**Note:** `file.choose()` would open a dialog box to choose file from you PC from any path.

If your `txt` file is tab separated, you can include `sep = "\t"` argument to `read.table`.

`header=TRUE` would come if you have column names in your text file, if not then it should be set to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

R told you that he cannont find your file. you have 2 options:

1) type **getwd()** in the terminal. It will show your path to the working directory. So put your file in that folder and it should work.

2) find the path of your file ex C:/doc/TransaniaIncomes.txt add the path to your read.table() function.

```
read.table("C:/doc/TransaniaIncomes.txt", header=TRUE)
```

tips: Make sure your file name is written correctly.