# How to read a text file folder to convert to corpus for word analysis?

Tags: r, analysis, sentiment-analysis, corpus

I'm using Rstudio.

And I have a folder ("/datahome/mario/datasets/robson/CLAY_Arquivos_PDF/TXT") with 5012 articles in ".txt", which need to be transformed into a corpus, into a database for word analysis.

```
Arquivos_TXT<- "/datahome/mario/datasets/robson/CLAY_Arquivos_PDF/TXT"
file_list <- list.files(path=Arquivos_TXT, pattern="*.txt")

file_list
```

I have found commands for individual text.

```
#Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518038/error-when-using-read-table

#getwd("~/datahome/mario/datasets/robson/CLAY_Arquivos_PDF/TXT")

setwd("/datahome/mario/datasets/robson/CLAY_Arquivos_PDF/TXT")  # The .txt file would be in TextFile folder
#read.table("1-s2.0-S0141391014003954-main.txt", header=TRUE)
read.table(file.choose(), sep="\t", header=TRUE)  # Choose "TransaniaIncomes.txt"
```

What I need to do is to a folder that has a set of "txt" files. So that they can be analyzed together. What is the correct command for this analysis?

I'm already grateful to everyone who helps me.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I watched the video on Youtube youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg ; this deals with file in ".csv". My files are in ".txt"., which are inside folder. And I need to turn these files into corpus.